# Inserting array containing multiple arrays into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im trying to insert the following array into my table to no avail. I tried several examples but none worked.

Each POST array contains two strings from an input form (each string from an input row) and the $data keys are of the same name of the columns in the table.

How do I insert this data into two rows with a single query?

```
$data = array(
    'user_id' => $_POST['user_id'],
    'order' => $_POST['order'],
    'type' => $_POST['type'],
    'series' => $_POST['series'],
    'repetition' => $_POST['repetition'],
    'load' => $_POST['load'],
    'pause' => $_POST['pause']
        );
```

EDIT.: Could swear I had copied the query.

```
$columns = implode(',',array_keys($data));
$values  = implode(',',array_values($data));

$query = " INSERT INTO userdata ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

Comment: It might help to include the code you've tried and let us know specifically what went wrong.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this type of array like this

```
$fields=" ".implode(",",array_keys($data))." ";
$data="'".implode ("','",$data)."'";
$query ="INSERT INTO table_name ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
if($query){
     mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Its trying to insert all the values into a single row